# Table moves after switching the Activity in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to write a simple App for Android and I have a problem, hope You could help)
I'm adding rows to my table dynamically. Everything is ok before I switch an activity. When I move to another Activity and try to come back, all Items in my table are moved. Probably something is wrong in my code, because I'm new to android development and actually to XML. Thank you in advance for Your help!

my XML code:

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">`


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/members"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dip"
            android:text="Mitglieder:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tblmembers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </TableLayout>

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/add_new_member"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_color"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:text="Neues Mitglied"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dip"
            android:text="Zahlungshistorie:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/bill_history"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"></TableLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_new_entry"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_color"
            android:text="Neuer Eintrag"

            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<!--</ScrollView>-->
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Java Code:

```
enter code here

package hci.univie.ac.at.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Benne on 01.05.2018.
 */

public class SelectedGroupActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{
TableLayout tableMembers;
TableLayout bills;
TableRow tmrow;
TableRow tmrow1;
TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5;
Button btn_member;
Button btn_bill;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selectedgroup);
    setTitle("Gruppenübersicht");
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_border);

    tableMembers = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tblmembers);
    bills = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.bill_history);

    btn_member = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_new_member);
    btn_bill = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_new_entry);
    btn_member.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_bill.setOnClickListener(this);


    TableRow.LayoutParams lp= new 
TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    lp.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

    //First Rows to the table Bills
    tmrow1 = new TableRow(this);
    tv3 = new TextView(this);
    tv4 = new TextView(this);
    tv5 = new TextView(this);

    tv3.setBackground(d);
    tv4.setBackground(d);
    tv5.setBackground(d);

    tv3.setHeight(110);
    tv4.setHeight(110);
    tv5.setHeight(110);

    tv3.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    tv4.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    tv5.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

    tv3.setTextSize(18);
    tv4.setTextSize(18);
    tv5.setTextSize(18);

    tv3.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
    tv4.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
    tv5.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));

    tv3.setText("Beschreibung");
    tv4.setText("Summe");
    tv5.setText("Bezahlt von");

    tmrow1.setId(0);
    tmrow1.addView(tv3);
    tmrow1.addView(tv4);
    tmrow1.addView(tv5);

    tv3.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tv4.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tv5.setLayoutParams(lp);

    bills.addView(tmrow1, new 
TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    bills.setColumnStretchable(0, true);
    bills.setColumnStretchable(1, true);
    bills.setColumnStretchable(2, true);



    for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.mainGruppe.getMembers().size(); ++i) {
        //Adding members
        tmrow = new TableRow(this);
        tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv2 = new TextView(this);

        tv1.setBackground(d);
        tv2.setBackground(d);

        tv1.setHeight(110);
        tv2.setHeight(110);

        tv1.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        tv2.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

        tv1.setTextSize(18);
        tv2.setTextSize(18);

        tv1.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));

        tv1.setText(MainActivity.mainGruppe.getMembers().get(i));
        tv2.setText("");

        tmrow.setId(i);
        tmrow.addView(tv1);
        tmrow.addView(tv2);

       /* tv1.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tv2.setLayoutParams(lp);*/

        tableMembers.addView(tmrow);
        tableMembers.setColumnStretchable(0, true);
        tableMembers.setColumnStretchable(1, true);
    }
        //Adding bills
    for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.mainGruppe.getBills().size(); ++i){
        tmrow1 = new TableRow(this);
        tv3 = new TextView(this);
        tv4 = new TextView(this);
        tv5 = new TextView(this);

        tv3.setBackground(d);
        tv4.setBackground(d);
        tv5.setBackground(d);

        tv3.setHeight(110);
        tv4.setHeight(110);
        tv5.setHeight(110);

        tv3.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        tv4.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        tv5.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

        tv3.setTextSize(18);
        tv4.setTextSize(18);
        tv5.setTextSize(18);

        tv3.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        tv4.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        tv5.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));


tv3.setText(MainActivity.mainGruppe.getBills().get(i).getDescription());

    tv4.setText(String.valueOf(MainActivity.mainGruppe.getBills().get(i).getPrice())) ;
        tv5.setText(MainActivity.mainGruppe.getBills().get(i).getPayer());

        tmrow1.setId(i+1);
        tmrow1.addView(tv3);
        tmrow1.addView(tv4);
        tmrow1.addView(tv5);

        tv3.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tv4.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tv5.setLayoutParams(lp);

        bills.addView(tmrow1, new 
TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        bills.setColumnStretchable(0, true);
        bills.setColumnStretchable(1, true);
        bills.setColumnStretchable(2, true);

    }

}

/**
 * Called when a view has been clicked.
 *
 * @param v The view that was clicked.
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int tempid = v.getId();
    Log.i("ID: ", String.valueOf(tempid));

    switch (tempid){
        case (R.id.add_new_member):
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewMemberActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case (R.id.add_new_entry):
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, NewBillActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
    }

}
}
```

And these are results:
[Before changing Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMmRF.png)
[Coming back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kznge.png)

Thank You!

Comment: try to see what happens when you add all that code to generate the dynamic table rows to the method `onResume()` instead of `onCreate().

Comment: But firstly it need to be created, or should I just duplicate the code?